# CentOS start php script in background

Tags: bash, background, centos

I am trying to start program in background from command line:

```
[root@my]# php file.php&
[1] 16897
[root@my]# bg
[1]+  Stopped file.php
```

It always stopped doesn't matter which php to start, where the problem is?

Comment: This isn't a programming question, so it doesn't belong on Stack Overflow.  I suggest posting it on Server Fault or some other place.

Comment: if you are using a & I do not think you need to bg the process.

Comment: @drrcknlsn http://unix.stackexchange.com would have been better for something like this which is really about using unix rather than system administration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with nohup

```
nohup php -r 'while (true) { echo "a";}' &
```

works fine for me (on kubuntu).

---

*Note : standard output :*

the standard output is redirected to `nohup.out` (if it has not already been redirected); `nohup.out` is located in the folder from where you run the command in command line .

So be carful to handle output properly, otherwise you might end up with a very big file after a couple of days/months

---

*Note 2 : to stop the process :*

The final **&** which backgrounds the process will print the PID. To kill the nohup process, run :

```
kill {PID}
```

(with {PID} being the PID printed after you executed the " `nohup php -r 'while (true) { echo "a";}' &` " command).

You could alternatively use `kill -9 {PID}` if you need to force kill.

Comment: so does `nohup php newEmptyPHP.php &` . (various source, including http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/i-want-to-run-php-file-in-background-on-fedora-terminal-in-background-924352/ (doesn't give the solution, but gives trouble shooting ideas))

Comment: Attention reader ! After almost a month, I've discovered a 12G (!!) file called nohup.out . And it was only "a" in the file ! So yes, if it works in the background, the standard output is redirected to 'nohup.out' . It is located in the folder from where you run the command in command line.

Comment: How would you then stop a script from running?

Answer (score 2):

```
nohup php newEmptyPHP.php &
```

Works fine for CentOS!!! Thanks to Cedric!